# Насколько правильное решение задачи?

Tags: ооп, mysqli, база-данных, php

Здравствуйте! Учу php и хочу научиться все делать правильно сразу.

Написал такой код проверки, на сколько правильно, возможно надо как то заменить?
 К примеру если проект будет высоко нагруженный насколько хорошо такой код будет справляться, если таких запросов будет много?

```
  $url = $explode[1];

  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id`,`url` FROM `category` WHERE `url`='$url'");

  $myrow = $result->fetch_assoc();

  if($url == $myrow['url'])
    {
     // Выполняю что мне надо
    }

  $result->free();
```

Заранее спасибо.

P.S Это часть кода, id нужен для дальнейший работе, о безопасности все знаю.

Comment: Хочешь правильно сразу - делай на фреймворках. Yii, Lavarel, Synfony 2 и ещё куча разных.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, думаю не саммый лучший совет, не изучив нормально процедурный и объектно-ориентированный стиль переходить к фреймворкам.
 Я не прав?

Comment: @alex159,

>>> Учу php и хочу научиться все делать правильно сразу
В фреймворках есть место и процедурному и объектно-ориентированному стилю. А вот такой фигни точно нет.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, пожалуйста объясните что вы имеете ввиду под "фигней".
Я еще новичок укажите что я сделал не правильно.

Мне лично легче сначала написать свой "велосипед", который будет нормально работать. Что я потом мог использовать готовые решение без лишних вопросов и хотя бы немного понимая по какому принципу все работает.

ИМХО.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, покажите процедурный фреймворк, пожалуйста.  
@alex159, основываясь на собственном опыте, я бы просто не стал заниматься процедурным программированием в контексте PHP. Будет время и желания - пройдете то же самое на чистом си, заодно сможете исходники PHP разобрать.  
Что до самого кода, то вам гарантированно вернется запись с нужным URL, за это беспокоиться не следует, подобных багов у БД не бывает.

Comment: @alex159,

>>> Что я потом мог использовать готовые решение без лишних вопросов

Не надо такой код потом использовать. Не надо.

Comment: @Fike, в любом решении на любом ООП фреймворке найдётся достаточно мест, где код больше процедурный, чем объектный. Я даже искать примеры не буду.

Comment: @Fike 
Спасибо за ответ.
Не могли бы вы посоветовать какие либо онлайн учебники по MVC+ООП.

Желательно на русском, а то на английском плохо воспринимаю информацию.

То не давно пытался сделать свой велосипед на ООП, было куча вопросов на которых не мог найти ответы, а если решал задачу то в итоге оказывалась что я делал не так ка нужно было. 

Хочу написать свой простеньких MVC движок.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev если я вас правильно понял, вы хотите сказать что процедурный стиль лучше не использовать, а сразу использовать ООП. 

А если нужно написать простенький скрипт, не везде же совать этот ООП? 

ООП - это хорошо, но когда в меру...

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, если вы про использование всяких trim, то это потому что их еще в тип string не завезли и там особого выбора нет, кроме как самому создавать класс String. Однако это не процедурное программирование, `sort($array)` от `ArrayUtils::sort($array)` отличается только формально.

@alex159, не надо думать, что ООП - это какая-то надстройка, которая должна использоваться только в сложных случаях. Это парадигма, подход к программированию, решаемые задачи будут абсолютно идентичны.

> Не могли бы вы посоветовать какие либо онлайн учебники по MVC+ООП

Я сам до сих пор многого не понимаю

Comment: но все мое обучение сводилось к самостоятельному рытью и прочтению статей на википедии, кода, стандартов, а когда-нибудь я научусь вдумчиво читать спеки, надеюсь. В общем-то тут нет каких-то непреложных правил - есть стандарты и принципы, следуя которым можно написать красивыый код. Я бы посоветовал сразу прочитать про какой-нибудь SOLID и ознакомиться с PSR, понять их так, как это понимается на текущем уровне, и вернуться через месяц. MVC я более-менее впитал примерно таким способом, начав с объяснений в кукбуке Yii и постоянно пережевывая узнанное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SQL Injection. Пользуйся [PDO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/research/302421/php-pdo-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85) - это по вопросу безопасности
2. Пользуйся кэшем, чтобы не делать запросы в БД при повторных обращениях к странице - это по вопросу "под нагрузкой"
3. Такого запроса достаточно: SELECT `id` FROM `category` WHERE `url`='?'
4. И такой проверки: if ($myrow) { ... }
5. Ну и самый важный вопрос: а что тебе даст этот id?

Comment: 1. О безопасности я позаботился до этого. 
5. Данная переменная понадобиться для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: Насчет 4, спасибо действительно ступил.

Comment: Вот смотри - мой MVC фреймворк, который я написал "по памяти", за 2 вечера, чтобы решить тестовую задачу перед собеседованием: сокращатель ссылок https://github.com/pvolyntsev/url-shortener это реально MVC + ActiveRecord за пару вечеров. По логике похож на Yii, но, повторяю, написал я этот проект по памяти.

Форкни себе и изучай.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev спасибо, попробую разобраться в логике вашего фреймворка и что то для себя взять.

Только вот чего я и боялся я многие моменты там и не понимаю. По этому я и не хочу пока лезть в фреймворки. 

Но попытаюсь разобрать ваш фреймворк и понять как все работает.

Answer (score 2):

Странный код. Вы выбрали все записи, в которых `url`='$url', а потом ещё раз проверяете, url. Да, теоретически он там может быть другим, но это уже проблема MySQL. Поэтому, проверка не нужна.

Второе - переменная $url похоже приходит с внешнего мира. Поэтому, я бы ее проверил, заэскейпил хотя бы. Мало чего там. А ещё лучше - использовать [pdo](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/). А то поломают Ваш сайт:)

Если запросов будет много (очень много), тогда прикрутите memcache, или что будет популярно в будущем.

Comment: О безопасности я позаботился до этого. 
Не думаю если буду использовать mysqli, а не pdo мой сайт сломают.
т.к в нормальных руках если с mysql работать нечего не сломают.

mysqli выбрал потому что он мне больше понравился чем pdo. Думаю для само развития знания mysqli не повредит.

Насчет memcache спасибо что напомнили.

Comment: >>> Не думаю если буду использовать mysqli, а не pdo мой сайт сломают

Сломают. Я знаю способ обойти mysqli_real_escape_string. Другие тоже могут знать.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, думаю не обязательно использовать данную функцию. 

А использовать для этого другие методы типа своей готовой функции.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, @alex159 забудьте про mysqli_real_escape_string в mysqli есть bind params, в этом смысле  PDO нисколько не безопаснее, вообще выбор PDO/mysqli это вопрос вкуса и задач (с mysqli иногда быстрее и проще сделать что нить мелкое, с PDO получаем легкий способ писать не только под mysql) в любом случае, если хочется поддерживать независимое от базы данных приложение обертку придется писать/использовать даже не ORM.